# SQL statements with equals vs in

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say that someone came up to you and said we're going to cut down the amount of SQL that we write by replacing equals with `IN`. The use would be both for single scalar values and lists of numbers.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN (1)
```

Are these statement equivalent to what the *optimizer* produces?

This looks really simple on the surface, but it leads to simplification for two reasons:

1. large blocks of SQL don't need to be duplicated
2. we don't overuse dynamic SQL.

---

### Example

This is a contrived example, but consider the following:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tablea a
     JOIN tableb b      ON a.id  = b.id
     JOIN tablec c      ON b.id2 = c.id2
     LEFT JOIN tabled d ON c.id3 = c.id3
WHERE d.type = 1
```

... and the same again for the more than one case:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tablea a 
     JOIN tableb b      ON a.id  = b.id
     JOIN tablec c      ON b.id2 = c.id2
     LEFT JOIN tabled d ON c.id3 = c.id3
WHERE d.type IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

(this isn't even a large statement)

Conceivably you could do *string concatenation*, but this isn't desirable in light of ORM usage, and dynamic SQL string concatenation always starts off with good intentions (at least in these parts).

Comment: They should be equivalent. Have a look at the execution plan to be sure.

Comment: I think there are more appropriate style things to focus on than this, like table aliases, not using `SELECT *`, etc.  The query plan is the only thing that will tell you what the optimizer sees, and it can change based on indexes and statistics.

Comment: I have tested on 6 million rows table. And be affected rows are 150 thousand rows. The response are all the same.

Comment: Three comments: (1) why would you need string concatenation for this, (2) an IN list isn't going to help you avoid concatenation if it's provided as a parameter, and (3) you know that using equality/IN against any d column in the where clause turns your left outer join into an inner join right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: it's a simple example.  I'm sure you've seen some of the huge SQL statements that are sometimes necessary.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how you're going to change a big block of `=` to a big block of `IN` where it's really going to reduce your code or make things less prone to requiring concatenation/dyn SQL. Instead of showing a simple example that doesn't make sense, why not show something a lot closer to what you're doing? If you have to do string concatenation to write your `=` lists, you're going to have to do string concatenation (or splitting using a table-valued UDF) for your `IN` lists too. Maybe there is a better solution to both of these, but we can't spot them with useless examples.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The two will produce the same execution plan - either a `table scan`, `index scan`, or `index seek`, depending on if/how you have your table indexed.

You can see for yourself - [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) - See the section called "Using the Execution Plan Options".

Answer (score 23):

Those two specific statements are equivalent to the optimizer (did you compare the execution plans?), but I think the more important benefit you get out of the latter is that

```
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5
```

Can be expressed as the following, much more concise and readable (but semantically equivalent to the optimizer) version:

```
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

The problem is that when expressed as the latter most people think they can pass a string, like `@list = '1,2,3,4,5'` and then say:

```
WHERE id IN (@list)
```

This does not work because `@list` is a single scalar string, and not an array of integers.

For cases where you have a single value, I don't see how that "optimization" helps anything. You haven't written less SQL, you've actually written more. Can you outline in more detail how this is going to lead to less SQL?

Comment: don't have SQL Server infront of me right now.  I needed an opinion from the SQL Server world before I proceeded.  i.e. didn't want to do a DBMS specific change like this without a sanity check.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Still agree with others that there doesn't seem to be a logical thing to change, what is the purpose? Aren't there more important things to focus on that alternating between equivalent syntax?

Comment: re: less SQL.  Say the statement is quite massive with lots of joins.  It'd have less SQL because that whole block wouldn't be duplicated, and you wouldn't need to do and dynamic composition either.

Comment: Maybe you could show an example in your question so we understand this "optimization"... what is the "whole block" you're talking about? I see `WHERE id = 1` ... how is `WHERE id IN (1)` less SQL?