# Query Optimization (IN vs Equals to)

Tags: sql-server

It is just for knowledge only.

Can you please tell me which is an optimized query of below two:
(Please note I have only 1 string to pass)

```
select * from crm_prod..profile where first_name = 'Nishant';

select * from crm_prod..profile where first_name in ('Nishant');
```

Thanks in advance,
Nishant Khanna

Comment: Why don't you test it out yourself?

Comment: Use the query that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both would be the same. The query optimizer will translate it to the same plan.

"In" is used for multiple values and internally for sql server will be translated to (Name = "nishant" or name = "secondvalue" or name = "...." ) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered.

They do the same for a single quote string.

You can check this related post for a better explanation [sql statements with equals vs in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476332/sql-statements-with-equals-vs-in)